# Query returns null value

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia and I want to implement a very basic example to understand the concepts in Mongodb and Morphia. 
I have a Collection in Mongodb its name is `Users` documents in it conssit of an UserID and City. I want to give the UserID and have the City as output. to do this job I have written this Code:

```
        Mongo mongo=new Mongo();
        Morphia morphia=new Morphia();    
        Datastore ds=morphia.createDatastore(mongo, "rcfdb");
        morphia.map(User.class);
        Query<User> qr=ds.createQuery(User.class).filter("UserID",52005);
        List<User> l=qr.asList();
        System.out.println(l.get(0).getCity());
```

I have this UserID in document in Mongodb, but it returns me `null` if I change my code to:

```
System.out.println(l.get(0).getUserID());
```

then  I see 52005 in Output!!! It seems that my query is chaged to a list format and nothing more.

What should I do? How can I get the City by giveng the userID

Comment: Dumb question: is the "city" _really_ set for the user id 52005 in the right collection?

Comment: yes sair :). I am sure ;)

Comment: What does the document look like?

Comment: {
  "City" : "Newyork",
  "UserID" : 52005,
  "_id" : "43a5228e40c785850140c78588200000"
}

Comment: run this in the shell:

db.user.find({"UserID" : 52005})

and make sure it's the only document with that UserID.

Comment: thanks, I had two documents with the same ID, Now it works :)